# Changing header dynamically with set_partial in pyrocms

Tags: php, dynamic, header, partial, pyrocms

I like to overload the header partial at front-end. I have a module that customizes the header but it doesn't work. I tried using this one in index of my controller `->set_partial('header','header.html')`

and I have my `header.html` in my `module-name/views/header.html`, the header which is in `system/cms/themes/default/views/partials/header.html` does not override which should be and I don't know what causing it. I've seen it in this discussion: [here](https://forum.pyrocms.com/discussion/992/function-set_partial)

My controller is in this case if for front-end (filename is same as the name of module) then the `$this->template->set_partial('header','header.html');` doesn't work. Please help me as I started pyrocms a few days ago and a newbie web developer.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

How did you include your header partial in the layout file of your theme?
There are two ways: through the template or through the theme plugin.

If you want to be able to overload your header partial with `$this->template->set_partial()`, you need to include the header partial by using `{{ template:partial name="header" }}`.

If you would like to use your theme header and only use the injected header partial on some specific pages, you could do something like this:

`{{ if {template:has_partial name="moduleheader"} }}
   {{ template:partial name="moduleheader" }}
 {{ else }}
    {{ theme:partial name="header" }}
 {{ endif }}}`

And be sure to not use the same name for the partials (by this I mean filename and the name set in the set_partial functions). It won't work if you call it "header" in the theme and in the template.

And just as I wrote all of this, I've actually found a post on the PyroCMS Forums dealing with this: [post on overriding theme partials in a module](https://forum.pyrocms.com/discussion/25640/overriding-theme-partials-within-a-module)

Hope that helps!

Comment: Hi! thanks for answering. Actually I tried `$this->template->set_partial()` in my controller and `{{ template:partial name="header" }}` in my view. It doesn't overload the header, instead it is placed in the body section of the webpage, and the default header is still there. So, there are two headers when I used it.

Comment: make sure that the partial you're injecting with `$this->template->set_partial()` has a different name than the theme partial - don't use 'header' both times. As for the appearance in the body, I would have to see your layout file to help you. But you might have put it in the wrong place.

Comment: My screenshot: [here](http://i.imgur.com/XrvDZ0E.png)

my code in controller:
`$this->template
   ->title($this->module_details['name'], 'the rest of the page title')
   ->set('items', $items)
                        ->set_partial('headers','headers.html')
   ->set('items_exist', $items_exist)
   ->set('pagination', $pagination)
   ->build('index');`
------------------------------------------------------------------

my code in view:
`{{ template:partial name="headers" }}`

Comment: I highlighted the picture because the logo is white and it cannot be seen so it became blue.

Comment: well, do you still have `{{ theme:partial name="header" }}` in your template? without the if/else construct I've posted above?